# Want to print multi dimensional list with all 0 elements using for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Expecting below output

```
[[0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0,0]]
```

But getting error `"IndexError: list index out of range"`. 
What's wrong in this code.

```
r = 4
c = 5
list = []
temp_list =[]
for r in range(r):
    for c in range(c):
        temp_list.append(0)
    list[c] += temp_list
print(list)
```

Comment: `list` is an empty list, therefore `list[c]` is out of range no matter what `c` is.

Comment: Move the definition of `temp_list =[]` to be inside the outer loop. You need to re-initialize the list inside each iteration instead of reusing it (as you're doing).

Comment: `[[0]*c for _ in range(r)]` should do what you want.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: `list` is reserved keyword in python you should use another name for your variable instead and it would be good if you use different variable names for loop variable it might create problem later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `temp_list` inside the `for` loop and instead of adding the 2 `list` use `append` method to achieve the expected result.

```
r = 4
c = 5
list = []
for r in range(r):
    temp_list =[]
    for x in range(c):
        temp_list.append(0)
    list.append(temp_list)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

@PythonPitch - would you like to try this one-liner:
(as earlier suggestions in the posts, your initialization and `c` column &tmp_list is wrong!)

```py
r = h = 4
w = c = 5

Matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

print(Matrix)

# if you insist to reuse your original var. as much as you like, here is the `right` way:
r = 4
c = 5
lst = [[0 for _ in range(c)] for _ in range(r)]

print(lst)  

assert lst == Matrix   # it's silent, meaning they are the `same` content.
```

Comment: if we have 2 lists as below 
list1 = [1,3,6,7]
list2 = [5, 7, 8, 4]

how can i make a list3 from list 1 and list2. List3 must be below
list3 = [[1,3,6,7],[5, 7, 8, 4]]

Comment: In my initial code, i was trying with c instead of x in praveen's solution. A small mistake thats all. By the way your solution might give the same result. but i was looking to correct my code. Thank you so much for answering my question. really appreciate it.